# error Command failed with signal "SIGINT". when try to terminal the docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

I have a simple `node.js` web app.

```js
☁  node-app [master] yarn start                              
yarn run v1.17.3
$ node ./dist/main.js
Http server is listening on http://localhost:3000
^C
```

Start the web application in the localhost and use `control-c` terminal it. It works fine.

Now, I build a docker image for this node web application. Run the docker container and terminal it uses the same way `control-c`.

```sh
☁  node-app [master] docker run -it -p 3000:3000 node-app:1.0
yarn run v1.16.0
$ node ./dist/main.js
Http server is listening on http://localhost:3000
error Command failed with signal "SIGINT".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The docker container is terminated as expected. But it seems `yarn` CLI throw an error for this.

Dockerfile:

```
# install dependencies ...
# build ...
CMD yarn start
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I also recently faced similar problem (using npm).
With docker, you can add a --init parameter which will start an init process in your container that will listen for sig commands (like ctrl + c) and handle them.

in docker docs:

> The container’s main process is responsible for managing all processes
> that it starts. In some cases, the main process isn’t well-designed,
> and doesn’t handle “reaping” (stopping) child processes gracefully
> when the container exits. If your process falls into this category,
> you can use the --init option when you run the container. The --init
> flag inserts a tiny init-process into the container as the main
> process, and handles reaping of all processes when the container
> exits. Handling such processes this way is superior to using a
> full-fledged init process such as sysvinit, upstart, or systemd to
> handle process lifecycle within your container.

This article also helped me understand a little bit more:
https://medium.com/@BeNitinAgarwal/an-init-system-inside-the-docker-container-3821ee233f4b